# jQuery delay does not seem to give the correct delay for this kind of event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had some help today with a need and this is what I have come up with:

```
      $(window).keypress(function (e)
      {
          if (e.keyCode == 13)
          {
              $('#doCheck')
        .css('color', '#666')
        .delay(100)
        .queue(function (next)
        {
            $(this).css('color', '#00ff00');
            next();
        });

        doCheck('mark1');
      }

<input id='doCheck' type="button" onclick="doCheck('mark1'); return false;" value="Mark" />
```

The idea here is that when a user presses the ENTER key then the color of the button will change color for 100 milliseconds and at the same time I call a function called doCheck that will call AJAX.

My problem is that there seems to be some minimal delay of almost a second before the color of the button changes back to #666. I expect a much shorter time but even if I set the delay to 10 then it still seems to delay for 1/2 to one second. I should add that if I set a long delay like five seconds then it really does do the five seconds.

I can't see what's wrong here.

Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks,

Here is the doCheck function. The function works correctly. Just the button thing is giving me problems. Note that I just changed it to async: true

```
function doCheck(task)
      {
          var parms = {
              task: task,
              pk: $('#Q_PartitionKey').val(),
              rk: $('#Q_RowKey').val(),
          };
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              traditional: true,
              url: '/power/check',
              async: true,
              data: parms,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data)
              {
                  // $('#doCheckMark').attr("disabled", false);
                  // $('#doCheckMark').css("color", "#000");
              },
              error: function ()
              {
                  var cdefg = data;
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: 666 may cause satanic delays :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `doCheck` doing a synchronous call?  If so, the queued function won't get called until your ajax call returns... which might account for the unexpected delay.

The fix would be to ensure that doCheck's using a proper asynchronous call.

Comment: I have async: false,  Maybe this is my problem. But will it be okay to set to async: true?  I can't remember now why I decided on false.

Comment: can you post the doCheck method too?

Comment: thank you for all of your help everyone. It finally works. I guess i needed to set async: true.  I hope that doesn't effect anything else. So far it looks okay but I have to check into what that setting will do and why I had it set to false.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you want to change the color then wait for a time and change it back.  No need for queue.

```
$(window).keypress(function (e)
  {
      if (e.keyCode == 13)
      {
          $('#doCheck')
            .css('color', '#666')
            .delay(100)
            .css('color', '#00ff00');

          doCheck('mark1');  // make sure ajax only runs when correct keycode is pressed
      }
  }
```

I am curious if you are wanting this effect attached to the ajax call itself or ALL ajax requests from the page.  If so, try tieing in the color effect to the ajax request or use `ajaxStart` or `ajaxStop`.

Comment: The AJAX call takes around a second but I just want to make a quick change to the button for maybe 250 milliseconds. It would be tied to the Ajax start but would it not be the same just to put the above there just before the call to AJAX?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, we can continue to refactor it, but I wanted to make sure that it working this way.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work but maybe it's related to the async in the AJAX as another user just mentioned

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(window).keypress(function (e)
{
          if (e.keyCode == 13)
          {
              $('#doCheck').css('color', '#00ff00');
              setTimeout(function(){
                  $('#doCheck').css('color', '#666');
              },100);

              doCheck('mark1');
          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have found the solution, but please for the love of good practices, change your inline "onclick" to a jQuery pub/sub model.

Here is an [example on how to do pub/sub jQuery event handling](http://jsfiddle.net/xeHdZ/)